# Gradle war plugin pulls in javadoc and sources

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a strange problem. I have a project which creates a war file with some custom inclusions like images etc. So far it looks good. The only problem left is that gradle pulls in source jars/zips and javadoc jars/zip into my WEB-INF/lib/ folder of my war.

I thought it might be a problem with Idea but same results with the command line. I guess it has something to do with the dependency configuration?
I use compile and runtime scopes and my artifacts are resolved from Artifactory.

Can anyone point me to a direction where to fix that?

**Update:**

When i create a task:

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'allRuntime'
}
```

or

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'allCompile'
}
```

I'll get the sources as well. So it seems that it has something to do with the compile/runtime configuration. They're pulling the sources and javadoc. But why?!

Dependencies are declared like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile         group: 'org.drools',                    name: 'drools-core',            version: DROOLS_VERSION
    compile         group: 'org.drools',                    name: 'drools-compiler',        version: DROOLS_VERSION
    ...

    runtime          group: 'net.sourceforge.barbecue',      name: 'barbecue',               version: '1.5-beta1', ext: 'jar'
    ...

    testCompile     group: 'org.fitnesse',     name: 'fitnesse',                            version: '20130531'
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring the dependencies?

Comment: I just minimized the script to define the repo, include java and war plugin and defining the dependencies and it's still the same?!

Comment: Try `gradle :mywarproject:dependencies` from command line. Are the `javadoc` and `sources` dependencies listed?

Comment: No they're not included... hm.. Can it be somehow related to the descritor files? The descriptor files are ivy.xml files. Maybe that gradle uses all configurations that are listed?

Comment: Try `task printRuntime << {println configurations.runtime.files}` if the javadoc & sources aren't printed when running the task... it's coming from somewhere else

Comment: They are printed... hm. Okay. But why?^^

Comment: It seems to be a problem with transitive dependencies of modules build by  my company. For these modules in the artifactory gradle will also pull in sources and javadoc. This then also applies to the external dependencies of the company modules. Kind of unsure what happens here

Comment: Thank you for your Help Lance Java! That really brought me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another attempt... a bit hacky but might work

```
configurations {
   tempCompile 
   tempRuntime
   tempTestCompile     
}

dependencies {
    tempCompile "org.drools:drools-core:${DROOLS_VERSION}"
    tempRuntime "net.sourceforge.barbecue:barbecue:1.5-beta1@jar"
    tempTestCompile "org.fitnesse:fitnesse:20130531"
    ...

    compile configurations.tempCompile.asFileTree.matching {
       exclude '**/*-sources.jar'
       exclude '**/*-javadoc.jar'
    }
    runtime configurations.tempRuntime.asFileTree.matching {
       exclude '**/*-sources.jar'
       exclude '**/*-javadoc.jar'
    }
    testCompile configurations.tempTestCompile.asFileTree.matching {
       exclude '**/*-sources.jar'
       exclude '**/*-javadoc.jar'
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! :) Great thank you! I already switched to a maven style repository. Now I have the problem that my jars are inserted 2 or 3 times. But that's another issue. Thank you for all the answers! :)

Comment: Ok I had a copy and paste error. Now it all works as desired. Again Thank you very much! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

As we discovered in the comments, your dependencies are bringing in javadoc and sources as transitive dependencies. You can possibly exclude these by

```
configurations.all { Configuration config ->
    ['com.group1', 'com.group2', ..., 'com.groupN'].each { groupId ->
       config.exclude [group: groupId, classifier: 'javadoc']
       config.exclude [group: groupId, classifier: 'sources']
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not an ivy user so the selector (classifier: 'javadoc' etc) may need tweaking

Comment: Hey Lance thank you for the suggestion. I was thinking of something similar as well but unfortunately that didn't work. It says "Dependency exclude rule requires 'group' and/or 'module' specified. For example: [group: 'com.google.collections']". I'm using gradle 3.1. Maybe the "classifier" is allowed there?

Comment: Hmm... annoying you can't 'wildcard' the group. Updated to hard code the groupid's (hopefully not too many of these?)

Comment: I think the problem here is that gradle uses the DefaultExcludeRule here. That rule only has "group" and "module" as a property so I can't specify "classifier". I just tried to manage it with help of the DependencyResolveDetails but that didn't work either. Hard to believe it's so hard to do it :D

Comment: The situation is this: I have X modules which are build by ivy and ant. Now I need to update the build system to gradle. Both must work in parallel until everybody has changed. I'm gonna let gradle publish the artifacts to a maven repository and see if that solves the issue. Hopefully it does. Thank you for all your help! I really appreciate that!